# Comparing mysql Timestamp with last month's date

Tags: java, mysql

I've been trying to retrieve the records from database's table "logging" where the records has "actionTime" that is greater or equals last month's date, in order to retrieve all the logs for this month, but there's a problem i think in Java code, result set of executed query only returns one record repeated many times.
When i executed the query on mySQL database console it worked fine! but when i use the same query on Java it throws this problem!
Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM LOGGING WHERE actionTime >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'
```

This is the structure of the database table:
[image: table logging]

Java Code:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();

currentDate.setHours(0);

currentDate.setMinutes(0);

currentDate.setSeconds(0);

currentDate.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);

stmt = db.createStatement();

query = "SELECT * FROM LOGGING WHERE actionTime >= '2016-03-01 00:00:00'";

stmt = db.createStatement();

rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

ArrayList<Logs> logs = new ArrayList<>();

Logs log = new Logs();

    while (rs.next()) {

        log.setID(rs.getLong("ID"));

        log.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));

        log.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

        log.setActionDate(rs.getTimestamp("actionTime"));

        logs.add(log);

    }
```

Comment: Did you try with escape character `"SELECT * FROM LOGGING WHERE actionTime >= \'2016-03-01 00:00:00\'"`

Comment: Thanks for replying, but same result!

Comment: How does this have to do with sql server?

Comment: do you select a database (use databaseName)

Comment: I'm connecting to database using Database Connection object "db"

Comment: what is the error that is being thrown?

Comment: No error messages are being thrown.. but i have 6 records that match the condition, only one record, the most recent record, is added 6 times in the ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move log into while loop:

```
   while (rs.next()) {

    Logs log = new Logs();

    log.setID(rs.getLong("ID"));

    log.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));

    log.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));

    log.setActionDate(rs.getTimestamp("actionTime"));

    logs.add(log);

}
```

Comment: Thank you somemuch! it worked :)
How did i miss that!